# Error while running unit tests in debug mode in VS2017

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2017, nunit

While running my unit test in VS2017 in debug mode, after the build the run starts but immediately after i get an exception before any of my breakpoints are hit:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' 
Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' :'*The assembly       with display name   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter'   failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ***Could not     load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter' or one of its dependencies***. The system cannot find the file specified.*'

How can I figure it out where is this issue coming from?

The file in the exception message can be found under: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions and has the version 15.0.28307

The VS2017 that i use has the version 15.9.11

Comment: Have you tried if it helps after you add reference to it? Check if [this link](http://lejisblog.blogspot.com/p/binding-failure-assembly-with-display.html) helps. For vs2017, Go=>Debug=>Windows=>Exception Settings can find the Managed Debugging Assistant.

Comment: Hi, any update, if you create a new unit test project, the same issue persists? If so, please share a simple sample here by one-drive so that I can check it directly.